# Answers tab shows "this question does not have any answers yet" while answers are loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I have noticed that when one is viewing the answers tab, and the orientation changes, a message saying "this question does not have any answers yet" is displayed for a short time even though the question have many answers. This message is immediately replaced by the answer list.

I'm pretty sure that it can be avoided. Should not be a priority though. For the time being it should be replaced with something sensible like "Loading.." or what not.

Still present in 0.1.26, I'm using Android 4.3 in LGE Nexus 4.

Comment: Rotating refreshes the view, so for the brief second while it reloads, it doesn't have anything to display. This has been reported before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it can be avoided though. Should not be a priority though.

Comment: It should be replaced with something sensible like "Loading.." or what not for the time being.

Comment: "This tag is to be used for the Official Stack Exchange application only. Currently the application is out in private alpha testing for Android 4.1 and up only. When posting bug reports, **please specify the app's version**."

Comment: @BenVoigt Updated question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

Not only do you now see a fancy loading indicator when loading answers for the first time, you also no longer have to re-load answers after flipping your screen.

The changes will go out in the next update, 0.1.27

Comment: Thanks man. Very quick fix.